# Error regarding file directory in cmd

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, cmd

After performing the commands `cd C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Lenny-Boio`
and `npm install discord.io winston --save` I have been acquainted with the following message:

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\USERNAME\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\USERNAME\package.json'
npm WARN USERNAME No description
npm WARN USERNAME No repository field.
npm WARN USERNAME No README data
npm WARN USERNAME No license field.

+ discord.io@2.5.3
+ winston@2.4.0
updated 2 packages in 0.818s
```

I have node.js already installed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I have edited your post for better readability.  Hope that helps you :) Generally, using formatting increases your chances to get a meaningful reply.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to install a package for a specific project? If so, it's best to create a new directory for that project and run `npm init` first.

This creates a `package.json` file in your project directory, which contains your project's Node.js configuration and package dependencies (like `discord.io` and `winston` in your case).

You can find more information here: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json